# Basic 'print' & 'puts' Mac OS terminal commands not found

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, path, ruby

I followed this article to install & update ruby with a package manager but I clearly messed up somewhere.

https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-your-mac-everything-you-need-to-get-going/

If I try to 'puts' or 'print' anything I get `-bash: print: command not found` / `-bash: puts: command not found` returned.

'ls' & 'cd' commands still work for example, but `echo $path` returns nothing.

As you have probably guessed, I am completely new to code & stupidly copy pasted lines into the shell that I don't understand.

Is this a path issue?

Comment: lp works in place of print. i'm not sure what puts is supposed to do.

Comment: puts shows up on a man page but it doesn't work for me either.  When I do "which puts" it returns nothing.  looks like it's been removed from macs.  what are you trying to do.

Comment: `puts`, in this context, is a ruby function call.  The link you posted is asking you to use vim to write the corresponding ruby command into a `.rb` (ruby) file, then running that in the ruby interpreter.  This is not something type into a shell directly.

Comment: @vykor make it an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

- `print` is not a standard bash command. I think so because  `man print` returns no manual entry.
- `puts`  is a Standard C Library function and should be used inside a file and used as:

  > ```
  > #include <stdio.h>
  > puts(const char *s);
  > ```
  >
  > The function `puts()` writes the string `s`, and a terminating newline character, to the stream stdout.

  An example:

```
/* puts example : hello world! */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char string [] = "Hello world!";
  puts (string);
}
```

<sup>http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/</sup>

- `echo $path` returns an empty line. It is case-sensitive. Use `echo $PATH`.
- You need to save the ruby script in a file with appropriate file extension: .rb. Open Terminal, go the directory where the file is located using `cd path/to/directory` and run `ruby filename.rb` to see the results.

Comment: How to indent code block in markdown ?